# Nav bar comes on top of header

Tags: css

I have the following CSS code, and my problem is that my 
nav bar comes on top of my header block. How can I move
the nav bar straight down from the header?

```
header {                                                                                
    background: black;                                                                  
    height: 60px;                                                                       
    left: 0;                                                                            
    margin: 0;                                                                          
    padding: 0;                                                                         
    position: absolute;                                                                 
    width: 100%;                                                                        
}                                                                                       

header img {                                                                            
    float: left;                                                                        
    margin-right: 10px;                                                                 
    position: relative;                                                                 
}                                                                                       

header h1 {                                                                             
    color: white;                                                                       
    font: 26px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;                                            
    line-height: 60px;                                                                  
    margin: 0;                                                                          
    vertical-align: middle;                                                             
}                                                                                       

nav {                                                                                   
    background: black;                                                                  
    margin: 0;                                                                          
    padding: 0;                                                                         
    position: absolute;                                                                 
    width: 100%;                                                                        
}
```

Comment: Note that I reformatted your code for you, next time use the code option in the editor to better display code.

Comment: Please add your HTML, just your CSS isn't sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@H.A; you give `position absolute` to your `header` block & `nav` block . So, when you give `position absolute` to an element then the element remove for the normal flow

CSS:

```
nav { 
 top:60px;
 padding: 0;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Read this article for more http://css-tricks.com/791-absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Answer (score 3):

give the nav a margin-top that is the same height of your navbar.

```
nav { 
 background: black;
 margin: 0;
 margin-top:60px;
 padding: 0;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
 .navbar-fixed-top{ 

 position:static;

}
</style>
  </head>

  <body>
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="intro-message">
                    <h1>HOST</h1>
                    <h3>two is better than one</h3>
                    <hr class="intro-divider">
                    <ul class="list-inline intro-social-buttons">
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://twitter.com/SBootstrap" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Twitter</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-github fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Github</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Linkedin</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>   


   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top topnav" role="navigation">
        <div class="container topnav">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand topnav" href="/">Host</a>
            </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Sign up</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>

        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav> 


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for. Just copy the whole code in a html document and run it in the browser. thanks